# Cannot get the data due to "Value below was evaluated just now"

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, observable

Well, I spent a lot of time looking for help for this problem but nothing worked for me.
I'm getting an Array of Objects from my provider:

```
this.encarteProvider.getProdutosEncarte('encarte1').subscribe(prods => {
    this.produtos = prods;
    console.log(this.produtos);
});
```

In console, it shows:

```
[]
0: Produto
1: Produto
2: Produto
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
```

If I try `this.produtos.forEach(produto => ...)`, it does not show me nothing, because the Array is empty. I think it's because the data is get asynchronously and (like the Chrome's console says when I ckick in the `i` icon) "the value was evaluated just now", but why I can show in html using `ngFor` but can't get the data inside the .ts file ?

Comment: Could you create a plunker with mock json that showcases this issue? :)

Answer (score 3):

It's just a timing issue. When the page first displays, the data is not there so the ngFor does nothing. Later, when the data arrives, the Angular change detection picks up that the data is now available and it updates ... reexecuting the ngFor and it works.

You don't show where the forEach is executed in the code ... but my guess is that it is before the data is retrieved. That is why it is empty.

Try moving that code to *within* the `subscribe`.

```
this.encarteProvider.getProdutosEncarte('encarte1').subscribe(prods => {
    this.produtos = prods;
    console.log(this.produtos);
    this.produtos.forEach(produto => ...);
});
```

That way the code won't run until *after* the data is retrieved.

I tried it in my code like this:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this._productService.getProducts()
            .subscribe(products => {
                this.products = products;
                this.products.forEach(product => console.log(JSON.stringify(product)));
            },
                error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad. The `forEach` is inside the `subscribe`, like you put in example, but even so the array is empty.

Comment: I just tried it in my code and it worked fine? I added my code to the answer above.

Comment: I tried it here and the console doesn't show anything :( It's so weird... I am surprised because I used things like that all the time in other parts of project but in this page, everything goes wrong.

Comment: I tried to do what I want (for each element in `this.produtos`, show the value of a property) in another way: Calling a function that executes the `forEach`, but so, the foreach goes crazy and starts an infinite loop!

Comment: I fixed the issue by reassign the object again after final initialization after subscription i.e. this.productos = this.productos.splice(0,this.productous.length)

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed by reassigning the object again after subscription i.e.

**this.prodoctous = this.prodoctous.splice(0,this.prodoctous.length)**

Answer (score 0):

This may happen when you trying to render those subscribed data using *ngFor (Anuglar), It takes long time to render thats why it feels like a lil bit hanging.

So for this,

SOLUTION 1:

**Use Pagination from your backend to limit the data that are retrieving, and use a more button to retrieve more data if needed**

SOLUTION 2:

**Use datasource to render data instead of listing, this might render the data in less time than ngFor**